# Executing PowerShell scripts via python

Tags: python-2.7, powershell

I have this PowerShell script and I have manually executed this

```
powershell -Command "C:\shellcommand.ps1"
```

I am writing it as `subprocess.check_output("powershell -Command 'C:\shellcommand.ps1'")`

I am getting result as `C:\\shellcommand.ps1\r\n`.
Actually I am trying to run a batch file from the script. Manually it is running.

Could you please help me how I can able to call this in python

Comment: Your title and your tags differ. Could you please clarify?

Comment: from my python script, I am trying to call a powershell script using command prompt commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter `-Command` is for cmdlets, and `-File` is for scripts.

Try This:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File"C:\shellcommand.ps1"
```

I think it will work for you.